# Action of $Aut(UT_3({\mathbb{F}_p}))$ on the set of non-commuting elements of $UT_3({\mathbb{F}_p})$

Tags: group-theory

Assume that $G$ is the group of 3x3 unitriangular matrices over the field of $p$-elements $\mathbb{F}_p$. Furthermore, assume that the group of automorphisms of that group, $Aut(G)$, acts on $G$. Do you know how can we prove that this action, acts transitively on the set of non-commuting pairs of $G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group can be defined by the presentation 
$$\langle x,y \mid x^p,y^p,[x,[x,y]],[y,[x,y]] \rangle,$$
where $x$ and $y$ can be any ordered pair of non-commuting elements of $G$. The result follows.

Comment: maybe you mean that the homomorphism who sends $x$ to $y$ and $y$ to $x$ is automorphism right?

Comment: No I didn't mean that (although it is true).  I meant that if $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are any two ordered pairs of non-commuting elements of $G$, then $G$ is defined by the corresponding presentations on the ordered generating sets $\langle x,y \rangle$ and $\langle x',y' \rangle$, and so there is an automorphism of $G$ mapping $x \mapsto x'$ and $y \mapsto y'$.